# Elliptic curve group - associativity when some points are equal

Tags: elliptic-curves, projective-space, associativity

The associativity of the [addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law) on an elliptic curve is usually proved using [Cayley–Bacharach theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Bacharach_theorem), which is fine as long as there are nine distinct points to work with.

The case when some of these points are equal is rarely taken into account and doesn't seem straightforward to me. Is there a not-too-advanced way to deal with it?

Terence Tao [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/pappuss-theorem-and-elliptic-curves/) mentions ‘a perturbation (or Zariski closure) argument’ to fix up the proof. What does that mean exactly?

Comment: I am guessing that what T.Tao meant is the following. The associativity law can be written as an equation using rational functions of the coordinates of the involved points. Therefore the associativity law will hold in a Zariski closed set. If you can show that that associativity law holds when the points are distinct, then you know that it will hold in a Zariski dense set. The points will be distinct unless they satisfy some equations, which happens in a complement of a Zariski closed set. In an irreducible variety a non-empty Zariski open set is always Zariski dense.

Comment: Yes, what Jyrki says is the intended argument. If you find that conceptually unsafisfying, there's a proof that doesn't require this kind of casework using an alternative definition of the group law - the terms to look up are divisor class group, Picard group, and/or Jacobian.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I know you commented quite some time ago. However, would you mind ellaborating a bit on, 1. 'The points will be distinct unless they satisfy some equations' - I suppose this will shed some light on why it happens in a complement of a Zariski closed set... And 2. How one concludes from you comment that the associativity law then holds in the case of coincident points as well.